# RequireJS/CodeMirror (sql mode) - how to make it work

Tags: requirejs, codemirror

I'm just starting out with CodeMirror (4.1) and am using RequireJs. (I'm also using ReactJs  but I'm pretty sure this is not the problem)

I have obviously not got it configured correctly. I would be grateful if someone could point out my error.

My config looks like this

```
require.config({

deps: ["main"],

paths: {
  ...
  codemirror:          "../../external/codemirror/codemirror-4.1/lib/codemirror",
  cmsql:               "../../external/codemirror/codemirror-4.1/mode/sql/sql"
},

shim: {
  ...
  codemirror:          { exports: "codemirror" },
  cmsql:               { deps: ["codemirror"],  exports: "cmsql" }    
}
```

});

and the module I am instantiating is as follows :

```
define(['jquery', 'react', 'codemirror', 'cmsql'],
function ($, React, CodeMirror) {

return React.createClass({

  render: function () {
    console.log("render-editarea");
    return (
      <textarea id="editarea">
      -- Comment here
      SELECT ID 
      FROM [Patient Demographics]
      </textarea>
    )
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {                  
    var editorNode = document.getElementById("editarea"); 
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(editorNode, {        
      lineNumbers: true,
      matchBrackets: true,
      indentUnit: 4,
      mode: "text/x-sql"
    });          
  },

  });
});
```

The CodeMirror manual appears to show this configuration when using module loaders.

I can see the effects of CodeMirror in terms of say line numbers etc but not in terms of syntax colouring

[image]

So any help would be gratefully received.

S

Answer (score 4):

Why is it as soon as you post something ...

The answer was (once I'd digested the manual a bit more)

```
require.config({

  deps: ["main"],

  paths: {
    cm:                  "../../external/codemirror/codemirror-4.1"
  },

  shim: {
    ...
  }

});
```

and

```
define(['jquery', 'react', 'cm/lib/codemirror', 'cm/mode/sql/sql'],
  function ($, React, CodeMirror) {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this solution. It worked for me. In require, point to the base CodeMirror directory, and then reference is as seen above. CodeMirror appears to use relative paths that seem to confuse require (it may be the other way around).